# What is the right way to iterate sum after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

As shown in the image below, what is the right way to iterate? Or get the issuer as a single list object?

```
dl_df.groupby(['Issuer']).sum()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `DataFrame.groupby()` and `sum()` along with `reset_index()` will be way to go.

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   A   B
0  1  10
1  1  12
2  1  11
3  1  10
4  2  11
5  2  12
6  3  14
```

### Best would be:

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index()
# df.groupby(['A']).B.sum().reset_index()
   A   B
0  1  43
1  2  23
2  3  14
```

### Another way around:

Using `as_index` to `False`  as per @jezrael mentioned.

```
>>> df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()
   A   B
0  1  43
1  2  23
2  3  14
```

### Applying Function:

Here the function passed to `apply` takes a DataFrame as its argument and returns a DataFrame. `apply` combines the result for each group together into a new DataFrame.

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x:  x.sum()).reset_index()

   A   B
0  1  43
1  2  23
2  3  14
```

Even one can Use `.pipe` when chaining together functions that expect Series, DataFrames or GroupBy objects.

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].pipe(lambda x:  x.sum()).reset_index()
```

Another approach `np.sum()` , First you need to convert your list ie `['B']` into a numpy array then use `sum()` function along with `apply()`  and lastly `reset_index()`.

```
>>> df['B'] = df['B'].apply(np.array)
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(np.sum).reset_index()
   A   B
0  1  43
1  2  23
2  3  14
```

**Note:** Here apply is not an efficient method but as its doable way hence i'm intacting it for posterity rather than removing ..

I don't know if something as follows you are looking for:

### Getting values into a list format:

```
>>> df.groupby(['A'])['B'].sum().values.tolist()
[43, 23, 14]
# df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(np.sum).values.tolist()
```

OR:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg({'B': 'sum'}).values.tolist()
[[43], [23], [14]]
```

Comment: there is no more straightforward way?

Comment: no, apply here is bad solution, need `df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index()` or `df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()`. Apply is used for some custom function, not `sum`

Comment: I notice it, but it is best solution, apply should be commented or removed.

Comment: check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions)

Comment: thanks @jezrael I read your comment / answers over at other posts too, so the real cause is the `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: @drhanlau - Not sure if understand, problem is why there is first 'column' different like second? Because if check `df = dl_df.groupby(['Issuer']).sum()` and `print (df.index)` it is no `MultiIndex`, but Index.

Comment: maybe add this dl_df.groupby(['Issuer']).sum().values.tolist()

Comment: @RafaelC, sure..

Comment: for key,item in result.iterrows():    print(item['A']," [Sum: "+ str(item['B'])+']')   you can iterate the resulting dataframe from the groupby and reset_index()